# Some properties missing in req.body inside multer middleware

Tags: node.js, multer

I have a client application that posts some `formData` to my node backend. The data coming from the client is initially an object that contains a `files` property among others. Before posting to the back-end, I convert the object to `formData`.

```
// client.js file
const person = {
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  age: 19,
  files: [File, File, File],
  occupation: '',
  status: 'active',
}

person.occupation = this.getOccupation(); // getOccupation() is defined somewhere in the file

const formData = new FormData();
Object.entries(person).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key === "files") {
    for (let i = 0; i < person[key].length; i++) {
       formData.append("files", person[key][i]);
    }
  } else {
     formData.append(key, value);
  }
});

// The following logs output the correct information so we're good until this point
console.log(formData.getAll("files"));
console.log(formData.get("occupation"));
console.log(formData.get("status"));

this.submitData(formData); // Posts to the backend
```

The data is posted to a route in the node backend with the multer middleware - `uploadFiles()`.

```
const submitDataOptions = {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads/users/files",
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log('Request body');
      console.log(req.body);
      console.log('Occupation');
      console.log(req.body.occupation);
      console.log('Status');
      console.log(req.body.status);
      const ext = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
      const datetimestamp = Date.now();
      const fname = `${datetimestamp}.${ext}`;
      cb(null, fname);
    },
  }),
};

uploadFiles() {
  return multer(submitDataOptions).array("files");
}
```

The files get uploaded just fine but when I `console.log(req.body)`, I notice that an object with only the properties `email` and `age` is returned. Logging `occupation` and `status` returns `undefined` in either case. The multer documentation says that `req.body` will contain the text fields if there were any but in this case I cannot find those.

What is the issue here?

Comment: don't check in ```req.body```, check in ```req```. You should get req.files for the uploaded files and req.occupation, req.status should contain your uploaded data. Thats because you sent a request with formData, so req.body wont get populated.

Comment: req.status and req.occupation are both undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.body` might not have been fully populated yet. It depends on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

So just put the files last in your object:

```js
const person = {
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  age: 19,
  occupation: '',
  status: 'active',
  files: [File, File, File],
}
```